# Atomically move and rename a Path instance

Tags: java, file

Given a `Path path` instance, I have the following questions:

1. How do I rename the file at which the `path` points, without resorting to the old `File` API if possible, I have not been able to find it anywhere yet?
2. Is it possible to atomically both move a physical file to a new directory and rename it at the same time?

I am using Java 8, new things for the `Path` class got added in for sure, not sure if the are of any help answering this question though.

Comment: You can just use [`Files.move`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) to move a file. If you have a directory this is very tricky for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding your first question, since Java 7 you can use [`Files#move`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-):

```
Files.move(path, targetPath);
```

If you need it to be atomic, you can use the `ATOMIC_MOVE` option:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE;

Files.move(path, targetPath, ATOMIC_MOVE);
```

Note that:

- this can fail with an `AtomicMoveNotSupportedException` if the option is not supported (for example if you are moving a file from a local hard drive to a network location).
- The `REPLACE_EXISTING` option, if used, is ignored and if the target file exists then it is implementation specific if the existing file is replaced or this method fails by throwing an `IOException`.

Comment: Would it also be possible to specify that the extension should remain the same?

Comment: @skiwi extension? A path has no notion of an extension at all

Comment: @skiwi I'm not sure I understand - you do what you want: `Files.move(Paths.get("someFile.someExtension"), Paths.get("otherFile.sameOrDifferentExtension");`.

Comment: Note: may be worh talking about `Path.relativize()`, `Path.resolve()`. Although (and this is VERY important) these two operations will NOT work if these two `Path`s are from _different `FileSystem`s_: in this case it throws a `ProviderMismatchException` (unchecked!!)

Comment: @assylias I want to move an existing path/file with some extension to a non-existing path that has the same extension. I don't see such option at the `StandardCopyOption`s, so I suppose it is not there.

Comment: @skiwi again, there is no such thing as an extension; a name is a name. `foo.txt.bar.whatever.meh` is a name.

Comment: @skiwi I still don't understand - you can keep the same file name, or use a different one with the same extension or anything you want.

Comment: @skiwi use `final Path destinationFile = destinationDir.resolve(sourceFile.getFileName())` and that is all; you don't care about extensions. Again, they _don't exist_. Extensions are nothing but a convenience.

Comment: Unfortunately ATOMIC_MOVE has another gotcha - it overwrites the destination file unconditionally even if you haven't set REPLACE_EXISTING.

Comment: @Trejkaz good catch, although it may or may not behave that way - see the last bullet point in my edit.

Comment: @assylias yeah, the API is very wishy-washy about that sort of stuff. It's the main thing that bugs me about it and makes me consider writing a replacement filesystem API.

Answer (score 1):

Moving and renaming a file are essentially the same operation, so you want to use the [`Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-):

> Move or rename a file to a target file.

In terms of forcing it to be moved atomically, using the [`StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html#ATOMIC_MOVE) copy option causes the following:

> The move is performed as an atomic file system operation and all other options are
>   ignored. If the target file exists then it is implementation specific if the existing file
>   is replaced or this method fails by throwing an `IOException`. If the move cannot be
>   performed as an atomic file system operation then `AtomicMoveNotSupportedException` is
>   thrown. This can arise, for example, when the target location is on a different
>   `FileStore` and would require that the file be copied, or target location is associated
>   with a different provider to this object.

Comment: Yes sorry. JavaDoc link was correct - text was wrong :-(